# curl format for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl

I want to send this via curl:

```
{
  "clientID": "9J8pM7Y…",
  "data": [
    {
      "photoId": 1,

      "success": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Ι was trying to send it like this:

```
$body = str_replace('\"','', wp_json_encode( [
        'clientID' => $clientid,
        'data' => ['photoId' => $photoId, 'success' => true]
    ]))
```

But then it was a json object not an array of json objects as needed. I tried sending it like a string but with no success:

```
$body ='{"clientID":"'.$clientid.'","data":[{"photoId":'.$photoId.',"success":true}]}';
```

Here is the whole curl:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/js/RDCJS/UpdatePhotos/",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$body,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Why are you removing the quotes? That creates invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Add an array around the `data` value.

```
$body = wp_json_encode( [
        'clientID' => $clientid,
        'data' => [['photoId' => $photoId, 'success' => true]]
    ]));
```

Don't remove the `"` characters, that produces invalid JSON.